# c++ incorrect checksum for freed object-

Tags: c++

I am getting this error (memory location varies between runs):
Freeing memory!
Image_Processing(6282,0x100091000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1212121212121212: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

in this point it crashes : //delete  m_data;

```
class Uint8Image {
public:
    uint32_t m_w;
    uint32_t m_h;
    uint8_t *m_data;


    Uint8Image(uint32_t w, uint32_t h): m_w(w), m_h(h), m_data(0)
    {
        m_data = new uint8_t(w*h);
    }

    Uint8Image(const Uint8Image &obj) ;

    Uint8Image& operator = (const Uint8Image &D ) {
        if(this != &D)
        {
            delete [] m_data;
            m_w= D.m_w;
            m_h = D.m_h;
            m_data=new uint8_t(m_w * m_h); // deep copy the pointer data
        }
        return *this;
    }

~Uint8Image()
    {
        std::cout << "Freeing memory!"<< std::endl;
    delete  m_data;   // it crashes here
    m_data = NULL;
    }

};

class MeniscusFinderContext {

public:

    MeniscusFinderContext( uint32_t m_a,  uint32_t m_b):

    {
      m_input_image = new Uint8Image(m_a,m_b);

    }

    ~MeniscusFinderContext()
    {
       delete m_input_image;
       m_input_image = NULL;

    }

Uint8Image m_input_image;};

//The function that calls:
```

// Taking input through option-parsing,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]{
const char *file_name = options[INPUT].arg;

    std::ifstream file_stream(file_name,
                              std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    char buf[256];
    char *sEnd;
    file_stream.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(buf[0] != 'P' || buf[1] != '5') {
        std::cerr << "invalid input PGM file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    file_stream.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    while(buf[0] == '#') file_stream.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    uint32_t m_a = strtol(buf, &sEnd, 10);
    uint32_t m_b = strtol(sEnd, &sEnd, 10);

    MeniscusFinderContext M(m_a,m_b);


    file_stream.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    while(buf[0] == '#') file_stream.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    if(atoi(buf) != 255) return 3;
    file_stream.read((char *)M.m_input_image->m_data ,m_a * m_b);
    if(!file_stream) {
        std::cerr << "only got " << file_stream.gcount() << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }
    file_stream.close();
return 0;
}
```

Edit: I'm running it and sometimes it runs while others it gives me the error. Seems to be at a random order. Any hints would be really helpful.
I already have checked all the related answers in stack overflow, but could nt figure it out.

Comment: Please try reformatting your post and your code, it's really hard to read. To reformat code in Visual Studio you can select all (Ctrl+A) then press CTRL+K+F

Comment: user2176127 is it fine now?

Comment: `m_data=new uint8_t(m_w * m_h); // deep copy the pointer data` doesn't copy anything.

Comment: @AshekDipro Why did you leave out the `UInt8Image` copy constructor?  You can't or should not use a class with two-thirds of the "Rule of 3" implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
new uint8_t(w*h);
```

This allocates exactly one `uint8_t`, whose initial value is `w*h`.

You probably intended:

```
new uint8_t[w*h];
```

Otherwise, this:

```
file_stream.read((char *)M.m_input_image->m_data ,m_a * m_b);
```

will immediately overrun this buffer. The same bug occurs several times in the shown code.

```
delete  m_data;
```

Stuff allocated with `new[]` should be deallocated with `delete[]`.

In general, your overall approach is very error-prone. Instead of manually handling memory, in this fashion, you should be using `std::vector`, and iterators. Correct usage of C++'s containers greatly reduces the possibility of making these kinds of bugs.

Comment: But I am still getting this error: Image_Processing(6371,0x100091000) malloc: *** error for object 0x100600268: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug